# How to install glib >2.34 on debian wheezy?

Tags: debian, glib

When trying to install janus packet, I got that error message

> Requested 'glib-2.0 >= 2.34' but version of GLib is 2.32.4

Is it possible to install Glib >2.34 on Wheezy and .. how can I do that ?

```
configure: error: Package requirements (
                    glib-2.0 >= 2.34
                    nice
                    jansson
                    libssl >= 1.0.1
                    libcrypto
                  ) were not met:

Requested 'glib-2.0 >= 2.34' but version of GLib is 2.32.4
```

Comment: glib? not glibc?

Comment: This is exacty the error I have !

Answer (score 0):

The `janus` package is only available on the Debian [Sid](https://packages.debian.org/sid/janus), the Janus dependencies can not be solved on debian wheezy.

[Documentation](https://janus.conf.meetecho.com/docs/resources.html)